# Layers added via layer definition file are not rendered

Tags: qgis

I've saved layers and layer groups to definition files so I can reuse them easily. However, when I add them into a project (Layer->Add from Definition File), they don't get rendered in the map. I've tried zooming them, unclicking and clicking the Render checkbox. Still nothing.

I'm not a QGIS expert, but newly-added layers are always rendered correctly.

These (vector) layers are nothing but shape files with corrected geometries.

What am I missing. How do I get these layers to render?

QGIS v3.22.4-Białowieża, Desktop for Mac